# Pass a sentence to a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, cin

How do i take a sentence, with spaces and upper and lowercase letters, as an input to a char array, e.g char arr[]. Is there any way to do this without using the cstring library?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
int palindrome(char arrC[], int indexS, int indexE) 
{ 

    if(indexS>=indexE)
        return 1;
    if(arrC[indexS] == arrC[indexE])
        return palindrome(arrC, ++indexS, --indexE);
    else 
        return 0;
} 
  
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 

    //string arrC = "A man a plan a canal Panama";
    char arrC[50]; //= { 'c', 'i', 'v', 'i', 'c' };
    cout<<"Enter your string: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, arrC);
    int size = sizeof(arrC) / sizeof(arrC[0]); 
    if(palindrome(arrC, 0, --size)==true)
        cout << "The string is a palindrome!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The string is not a palindrome. It's just a regular string." << endl;
  
    return 0; 
}
```

This is the error it's giving

[image]

Comment: `getline` works on char arrays.

Comment: @stark fgets is used with files. I need the user to input the sentence directly on console and after taking input of this sentence store it in a char array

Comment: @john i tried using getline but it'snot working. It give this error:
```
error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, char [50])’
  getline(cin, arrC);
```

Comment: Show us the code and the error with an *edit to your question*. In comments code just turns into mush.

Comment: @MahreenAthar Show the code. getline works with char arrays, so you did something wrong. Without seeing the code it's hard to say what.

Comment: @john i just edited this and added the code and the error. I want to input this "A man a plan a canal Panama" in a char array

Comment: Try this, `cin.getline(arrC, 50);` Honestly you could have looked that up.

Comment: BTW your size calculation is wrong, it gives you the size of the array, not the size of the string that is in the array,

Comment: @john yes i fixed the input thing. That was a dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: @MahreenAthar This would be easier with `std::string`, you could have used the `getline` you are familar with, you could have used the `size()` method to get the size of the string. There are no disadvantages at all. But if you must use a char array then use `strlen(arrC)` to get the size of the string.

Comment: @john i did use string first and this program worked but i needed to use char array and i got stuck. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223842/discussion-between-mahreen-athar-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do this, is to use `std::cin.getline()`, use it as follows:

- First argument to it should be the c style string array you want to store the input in.
- Second argument passed in should be the maximum number of characters to write to 'your first argument' (including the terminating null character).

Here is an example of one I quickly made:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    char my_arr[100]{};
    std::cin.getline(my_arr, 100);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MahreenAthar No worries!